# Where to populate data? Inside or outside method?

Tags: javascript

I have a dilemma on where to populate the data.

Below are 2 kind of methods to compute the total price of a quotation:

```
// example in javascript
function computePrice(quotation) {
    var totalPrice = 0.00;
    var items = quotation.getItems();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        totalPrice += items[i].getPrice();
    }

    return totalPrice;
}

QuotationDao.populateItems(quotation);
computePrice(quotation);
```

Another way of writing is:

```
function computePrice(quotation) {
    var totalPrice = 0.00;

    // Populate items in the quotation from database
    QuotationDao.populateItems(quotation);

    var items = quotation.getItems();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        totalPrice += items[i].getPrice();
    }

    return totalPrice;
}

computePrice(quotation);
```

I have asked my peers and received different inputs.

1. Method #1 is correct because code should not retrieve data in a function unless that function is purely created for retrieval purpose.
2. Method #1 is correct because it allow unit testing.
3. Method #2 is correct because no external dependency is required before calling the method, the method has high cohesion.
4. All method are incomplete, QuotationDao.populateItems(quotation) should be in a separate method like QuotationDao.getComputePriceData(quotation) with the result passed into computePrice like computePrice(computePriceData);

Do you have any advice on which route should I undertake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one applies [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which is also known as "principle of least knowledge", and [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), then one would like to write a code like this:

```
Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
totalPrice = q.getTotalPrice(); //Computation inside it
```

If the computation is bit complicated and does not involve just adding the values of various items within quotation, then, one may use separate method:

```
Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
totalPrice = PriceHelper.getTotalPrice(q); //Computation inside it
```

Both approaches are equally testable (appropriate mocks/stubs will be needed)

If you are still feel confused, then, ask yourself a question - "which approach gives me code that is easily understandable"  -  I found the book "Clean Code" really useful whenever I faced such dilemma

Comment: Thanks wand. but erm.. where would you populate quotation items? Inside getTotalPrice or fetchQuotation or another line in between like:

    Quotation q = DAO.fetchQutation(someCondition);
    DAO.populateQuotationItems(q);
    totalPrice = q.getTotalPrice();

Comment: What does populateQuotation do?

Comment: Hmm, 1 quotation normally have N line items such as product, quantity, pricing. populateQuotationItems will populate the items of a particular quotation. Only after population can computePrice work. This is because without population, quotation will have 0 items because they have not been retrieved from the database.

Comment: fetchQuotation should populate child entities like items.  If you use ORM like JPA (in Java world), the child relationships are fetched automatically (if you have defined mappings), and no additional method has to be written.

Comment: Hmm ok, I guess you meant populateQuotationItems should be executed immediately after fetchQuotation so that it emulate the "auto" fetching (I'm writing in classic asp in a vendor specific framework so there isn't any ORM to utilise).

Comment: Either inside "fetchQuotation" or add a different methods saying "fetchItemsFor(quaotation)" so that for a reader of code it is clear.  The method like "fetchItemsFor" may be needed if source of data for quotation and items are different.  If both are coming from same DB, then, better to do population of items within "fetchQuatation"

Comment: Ok I shall go with the majority then, which is populating the items before running the method computePrice, thanks wand and fendy.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bad method structure for your data population method `QuotationDao.populateItems(quotation);`. Why is it bad?

1. It breaks [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). For a simple method such as populating data or generating data, accepting input and returning result will be more beneficial because it can be re-called and the result will be consistent.
2. The method is not self-documented. You don't know what the data type quotation is, what is needed to be performed to quotation beforehand, what is being populated, what is the population parameter.
3. It is not working in statically typed language such as java/C#. They need to have specific object type to be passed as parameter.

My suggestion is to have 2 different retriever or what you said DAO:

```
quotationDao.getQuotation = function(){
    var quotation = {};
    // populate quotation
    return quotation;
}

itemDao.getItems = function(quotation){
    var items = {};
    // get items
    return items;
}
```

Next, you can follow Wand Maker's answer about SRP and `Law of Demeter`. However his answer still breaks the `Law of Demeter`. It states:

- Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
- Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
- Only talk to your immediate friends.

In your current implementation, the closest friend of price calculation will be only items. They shouldn't know about quotation. So instead of using

```
Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
totalPrice = q.getTotalPrice(); //Computation inside it

//or

Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
totalPrice = PriceHelper.getTotalPrice(q); //Computation inside it
```

Instead use:

```
Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
Items i = itemDao.fetchItem(quotation);
totalPrice = i.getTotalPrice(); //Computation inside it

//or

Quotation q = dao.fetchQuotation(someCondition);
Items i = itemDao.fetchItem(quotation);
totalPrice = PriceHelper.getTotalPrice(i); //Computation inside it
```

Comment: Erm.. the language I'm using is jscript, so it's kind of weakly typed. I does have the 2 methods you suggest but I implement the populateItems method as a wrapper to associate the items with the quotation so that I can do a quotation.getItems() call.  Based on the suggestions you provide as an extension to wand maker, it looks like you are also suggesting that population of items should be done outside of getTotalPrice method.

Comment: Indeed. `getTotalPrice` is only associated with `items`, so it makes no sense to include/pass `quotation` to `getTotalPrice`. Unless quotation is taking part in price calculation, only then it is passed.

Comment: Suppose quotation is taking part in price calculation, then should populateItems be done outside getTotalPrice or inside?